# Applescript - Type in the system dialog view (eg: save, load)

Tags: applescript

I would like to type in a system dialog  (like those used by most of the OSX application for loading or saving).

So far, I am not able to get this to work though... I did try to run this, when the system dialog to save a file is open:

```
osascript -e ' tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "/tmp/test1.log"
    key code 36
    end tell'
```

When I run this; nothing happens; the system dialog view stay up, nothing get typed in it. Do I have to specify also the view by name? I did assume that since the app has focus, and the system dialog has focus, I can just type in it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample script that works for me:

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        keystroke "s" using {command down}
        delay 2
        keystroke "new file name"
        key code 36
    end tell
end tell
```

Note the delay between invoking 'save' and the actual typing -- you need to ensure the dialog is fully open before starting to type. Since your script is activated on save, you'd skip past the `keystroke "s"` step in my example and go right to the `delay`.

Also note System Events is informing the *process* to perform the keystroke. You need to ensure the proper process is being targeted in your script.

Lastly, have you configured your System Accessibility settings to allow this type of scripted interaction?

[Via Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AutomatetheUserInterface.html) To enable accessibility control for an app:

1. Launch System Preferences and click Security & Privacy.
2. Click the Privacy tab.
3. Click Accessibility.
4. Click the Add button (+).
5. Choose an app and click Open (in this case, Script Editor).
6. Select the checkbox to the left of the app.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Does this works also if you launch the script while you already called the save system dialog on Safari? Because I am having issues doing that; my script is not fully driven by Applescript, so I may run the script when Safari (or iTunes and so on), is already open, and has already on screen the system dialog screen to save.

Comment: You can certainly use AppleScript for that, but you may need to tailor it for your situation (e.g. `Tell process "your app name here"`)

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work. As long as you call the save dialog with the shortcut, it does work, but if you are jumping on the application while the dialog is already up, it won't be able to find it (I see nothing typed in the save window)